# Mailserver standard filenames?

Tags: email, imap, smtp, mail-server

I have 3 mailboxes (gmail, 2 from univeristy) and 3 mailclients (apple mail, k9, thunderbird, evolution at work). Getting the clients to work together is a pain in the ....

***What are the names for the mailboxes (files on server), which are the most likely to work with the majority of mailclients? Are there any standards?***

What I read a lot is "Sent", "Trash" and "Drafts". But some clients translate the names to german and Apple appends a whitspace and messages, e.g. "Sent messages". Confusing...

Google does its automated work right. Everything is setup correct. But the other two accounts have about 3 identical Mailboxes (Sent, Trash, Spam). Fortunatly I can ssh-in an check/change the filenames on the university accounts.

Comment: 1. How is this a question? 2. What is the question? I can't discern a question from the rant.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot the question mark. But imho the question is clear without the question mark.

Comment: It isn't clear to me. Are you asking why different email providers use different names for mailbox folders or are you asking why different email clients use different names for mailbox folders?

Answer (score 1):

I believe no here is actually answering your question here, but that  could be my pretentiousness :F

I also believe your looking for the file ***server*** instead of the file ***name***

Mostly any mail client supports the use of having a text field of username, password, and mail server for pulling the info. So with that in mind here's a handy dandy list :B)

http://ipadhelp.com/popular-list-of-email-name-servers/

But for GMail It's:

Incoming: pop.gmail.com

Outgoing: smtp.gmail.com

Port: 995

Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587]

Port for SSL: 465

***If you don't know which of these ports to use go for SSL `465` but if it doesn't work revert to `995`***

Google GMail Client Support Page: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

---

If your mail clients have only one field for mail server then just use: `pop.gmail.com`

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. +1 for that, but I really mean the files. Every mailserver has files for the mailboxes in MBOX format. I am just annoyed that each of the mailclients initializes different mailboxes. E.g. for my sent mails Thunderbird makes a "Sent" mbox, AppleMail "Sent messages" and K9-Mail "Gesendet" (german). This sucks.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r OHH! You mean the file system that actually keeps all the mail documents and sub-mailboxes. Alright, I see what your saying. But regardless, I don't believe google actually allows you to control via FTP something like that. Or am I misinterpreting?

Answer (score 0):

Forward all your mail to just one account, then use filters to sort them. One account, one client, and your problem goes away. It also means you have backups if you don't delete when forwarding. Having a personal copy of your work emails is a good CYA strategy.

Comment: Not a good idea. I want academic, work and private stuff to be separated.